# Library type list read from parcel

Tags: android, parcelable

Assume you have some Serializable class, that you have in some library (LibClass)

You have your own class

```
class Foo implements Parcelable {
   private List<LibClass> mLibraryList;

   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Foo > CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Foo >() {

   public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Foo (in);
    }

   public Foo [] newArray(int size) {
        return new Foo [size];
    }
   };   
}
```

The problem is - how to create a constructor from Parcel?

```
private Foo(Parcel in) {
   in.readList(mLibraryList, ???); // whoaps! where is the loader for lib class?
}
```

Comment: LibClass must implement Parcelable

Comment: I believe, there is a workaround. Because my LibClass is Joda Time lib class and only way to use it with this restriction - writing wrapper classes.

Comment: yes. add an intermediate class extends LibClass implements Parcelable that does the parceling